# c# - Return a generic interface dynamically

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm trying to return one of two repository instances based on a flag. My Repository Interface and implementation look like so:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T SearchForFirst(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    bool Has(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}

class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class    { ... implementation here ...}
```

And the method that is returning the one of two instances of a repository should look something like:

```
    public IRepository<T> GenerateRepository(bool flag)
    {
        if ( flag ) {
           return new Repository<MyFirstType>();
        } else {
           return new Repository<MySecondType>();
        }
    }
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how this should actually be written?

Thanks

Comment: That does't actually make sense.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I guess I'm just thinking about the problem wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That can only work if the two types share a common base type or interface, and only of the interface is covariant (which yours is not):

```
public IRepository<CommonAncestor> GenerateRepository(bool flag)
{
    if (flag) {
       return new Repository<MyFirstType>();
    } else {
       return new Repository<MySecondType>();
    }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to return an `IRepository` of an unspecified type; the generic members wouldn't be usable.